# Java Applet and Console

Tags: java, applet

I'm new in building Java applets
I want to show what it's display in my console in the Java applet, I know you should use the paint method, but I don't know how to call it in the code.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {        
    //Draw a rectangle width=250, height=100       
    g.drawRect(0,0,250,100);         
    //Set the color to blue      
    g.setColor(Color.blue);         
    //Write the message to the web page       
    g.drawString("Running",10,50);
```

This is what I currently have, the whole program it's made to run from the console in

```
System.out.println(x)
```

is there anyway to call something like

```
paint(x)
```

to show the same on the applet as is show on the console? Plus I need it to refresh constantly.

Comment: What do u mean by showing on the applet? Do you mean swing application to show the text on the form or panel?

Comment: 1) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle. 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: is there any other way? I have to build an html to call a java function and show the result, I don´t really know another way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a call to the superclass method. Put

```
super.paint(g);
```

before anything else.

If you want to display a message on the applet at the same time as on the console, you need to have a method that calls repaint();. The way I would set this up is to have an Arraylist of Strings. When you want something written to the applet output, you add the new String to the ArrayList, then call repaint(). Then, in paint(),

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList();
public void paint(Graphics g) {   
    super.paint();
    //Draw a rectangle width=250, height=100       
    g.drawRect(0,0,250,100);         
    //Set the color to blue      
    g.setColor(Color.blue);         
    //Write the message to the web page
    for(int i = 0; i<ar.size(); i++)
        g.drawString(ar.get(i), 10, 50); }
```

If you want a function that does this, you might write it like so

```
public void appletOut.println(String str){
   ar.add(str);
   repaint();
}
```

Finally, I question whether this route is really best for what you are trying to accomplish. I would suggest researching text fields and scrollbars and seeing if that might fit your parameters better.